# restrict https access with .htaccess to everything but 1 folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have the folder https_folder (including all subfolders and files) forcing https, but every other directory or file, utilizing http.

Folder structure:

1. foldera
2. folderb
3. https_folder
4. folderc

I tried to set it as followed, however i dont seem to get it working

redirect for http /https_folder

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} = 80
RewriteRule ^https_folder/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/httpd_folder [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

redirect for https non /market pages

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/https_folder [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /https_folder/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(https_folder)(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/https_folder/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to https if URI has https_folder
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^https_folder/? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

# redirect to https if URI doesn't have https_folder
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(?!https_folder/?)(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```